# Association Rules using Python with data in sentence form

Tags: python-3.x, sparse-matrix, text-mining, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I would like to calculate association rules from a text field from a dataset such as the one below **using Python**:

```
ID  fav_breakfast
1   I like to eat eggs and bacon for breakfast.
2   Bacon, bacon, bacon!
3   I love pancakes, but only if they have extra syrup!
4   Waffles and bacon. Eggs too!
5   Eggs, potatoes, and pancakes. No meat for me!
```

Please note that [`Orange 2.7`](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/2/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html) is not an option as I am using the current version of Python (3.6), so [`Orange 3`](http://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html) is fair game; however, I can not seem to figure out how this module works with data in this format.

The first step, in my mind, would be to convert the above into a sparse matrix, such as the (truncated) one shown below:

[image]

Next, we would want to remove stop words (ie. I, to, and, for, etc.), upper/lower case issues, numbers, punctuation, account for words such as potato, potatoes, potatos, etc (with lemmatization).

Once this sparse matrix is in place, the next step would be to calculate association rules amongst all of words/strings in the sparse matrix. I have done this in R using the `arules`package; however, I haven't been able to identify an "`arules` equivalent" **for Python**.

The final solution that I envision would include a list of left-hand and right-hand side arguments along with the support, confidence, and lift of the rules in descending order with the highest lift rules at the top and lowest lift rules at the bottom (again, easy enough to obtain in R with `arules`).

In addition, I would like to have the ability to specify the right hand side to "bacon" that also shows the support, confidence, and lift of the rules in descending order with the highest lift rules in regards to "bacon" at the top and lowest lift rules in relation to "bacon" at the bottom.

Using `Orange3-Associate` will likely be the route to go here; however, I cannot find any good examples on the web. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind? Orange should be able to pass outputs from one add-on and use them as inputs in another.

[image]

[**EDIT**]
I was able to reconstruct the case in code, but it is far less sexy:

```
import numpy as np
from orangecontrib.text
import Corpus, preprocess, vectorization
from orangecontrib.associate.fpgrowth import *

data = Corpus.from_file("deerwester")
p = preprocess.Preprocessor()
preproc_corpus = p(data)
v = vectorization.bagofwords.BoWPreprocessTransform(p, "Count", preproc_corpus)
N = 30
X = np.random.random((N, 50)) > .9
itemsets = dict(frequent_itemsets(X, .1))
rules = association_rules(itemsets, .6)
list(rules_stats(rules, itemsets, N))
```

Comment: Thanks @vijolica, I am not overly familiar with the Orange GUI; however, this type of output would do the trick. The fuzzy areas I have with this are 1) What format is your data (corpus) in? 2) What are you/Orange doing in the pre-processing phase? 3) Are you able to look at the Python program(s) used to run any of the 4 steps in this process? In other words, can we take the Python programs used in the Orange GUI and copy/paste into other Python IDE's? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ad 1) The usual format in Orange is tab-delimited, but you could essentially use Excel or .csv.
Ad 2) Preprocessing here is a simple default: lowercase, tokenize by words, omit punctuation, filter out stopwords.
Important! The sparse array required here is generated in Bag of Words which outputs word counts.
Ad 3) Unfortunately not yet. Orange wraps nltk and other Python functions, so you could, in theory, look at the Orange source code and try to extract valid functions. Not a simple task. :O

Comment: Thanks again for continuing to push forward on this! I have a couple more questions, but I will just ask one for now - When trying to install `orangecontrib.text`, I get the following error "PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels: -orangecontrib.text. I tried using pip, pip3, and conda, but did not have any luck within the Anaconda command prompt. Thoughts? Thanks again for helping me navigate through these hurdles.

Comment: The package is called orange3-text, orangecontrib is just for the import. Try `conda install orange3-text`.

Comment: that worked with pip install orange3-text for me, great! but that led to another issue: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Preprocessor' when running the `p = preprocess.Preprocessor()`...any thoughts on that one? Thanks again!